# Need a SQL Server function to convert local datetime to UTC that supports DST

Tags: sql-server, timezone, azure-sql-database, utc, dst

We are migrating an application to Azure, but currently all of our dates are stored as Eastern Standard Time. Since SQL Azure is on UTC and many of our dates are generated from a getdate() call, we're going to have issues if we leave everything as it is. It seems that the option that will provide the least long term headache is to just convert all of our stored dates to UTC, and have them converted to local time on the front end.

Unfortunately it seems that there isn't a built-in way to convert a SQL datetime from one time zone to another, and many of the solutions that I've found don't take daylight savings time into consideration. The solutions that I've found that do consider DST involve importing calendars and time zone tables and are extremely complex.

I'm just looking for something that will work for a single conversion, and it doesn't have to be pretty.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I wrote the following function that I believe will accomplish what I need.  Does anyone see any holes with this?  All of my dates are currently Eastern Standard Time, but my dates start around 2002 so I had to handle that law change in 2007.

I'm thinking I would use this function like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myDate = dbo.fnESTtoUTC(myDate)
```

Here's the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnESTtoUTC]
    (@pESTDate  DATETIME)
    RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TimeZoneOffset INT
DECLARE @Year INT
DECLARE @Day INT
DECLARE @DSTStart DATETIME
DECLARE @DSTEnd DATETIME

SELECT @Year = DATEPART(year, @pESTDate)

IF @Year >= 2007
BEGIN
    SELECT @Day = 8
    WHILE @DSTStart IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Second Sunday in March
        IF DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 3, @Day)) = 1
            SELECT @DSTStart = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@Year, 3, @Day, 2, 0, 0, 0)
        SELECT @Day = @Day + 1
    END

    SELECT @Day = 1
    WHILE @DSTEnd IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- First Sunday in November
        IF DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 11, @Day)) = 1
            SELECT @DSTEnd = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@Year, 11, @Day, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        SELECT @Day = @Day + 1
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @Day = 1
    WHILE @DSTStart IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- First Sunday in April
        IF DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 4, @Day)) = 1
            SELECT @DSTStart = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@Year, 4, @Day, 2, 0, 0, 0)
        SELECT @Day = @Day + 1
    END

    SELECT @Day = 31
    WHILE @DSTEnd IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Last Sunday in October
        IF DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 10, @Day)) = 1
            SELECT @DSTEnd = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@Year, 10, @Day, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        SELECT @Day = @Day - 1
    END
END

IF @pESTDate >= @DSTStart AND @pESTDate < @DSTEnd
BEGIN
    -- Date is in DST
    SELECT @TimeZoneOffset = 4
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Not DST
    SELECT @TimeZoneOffset = 5
END

RETURN ( dateadd(hh, @TimeZoneOffset, @pESTDate) )
END
```

Comment: The reason tables get involved is because it's impossible to reliably change a date between time zones since the definition for time zones themselves change over time (and geography is important too, e.g. not too many years ago Indiana didn't support DST, but it does now). How will you write a "single conversion" that accurately converts November 20th, 1996 *and* November 20th, 2013? I don't know off the top of my head, but I think one of those is in DST and the other isn't. Don't be afraid of an additional table. I've done exactly this and it worked quite well for a limited # of time zones.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but a suggestion. Split your design into n tier / MVC. So data, business, UI. Now, in your data layer store the date/time in UTC along with a timezone indicator of the source date/time. This means that ALL your date/times are normalised. Now in the business layer do the necessary conversation to a the required normalised "local" date/time (again based on the required TZ) for display in your UI layer. IMHO don't use SQL as your business engine - do that bulk of that work in your business layer. I hope this helps.

Comment: @robnick but something still has to be aware whether a timezone is in DST at the time or not. The presentation tier can tell if *today* is in DST, but not some arbitrary date (and don't just think about past dates, think future too). I fully agree that datetimes should be stored as UTC (and in fact set all my servers to UTC), but even if you are storing TZ + DST information along with a date, for future dates, you need to be able to adjust when some President decides to change the range of DST again (or obliterate it completely).

Comment: There's a reason not a lot of software handles this correctly - it's a hard problem to solve. Schedule a meeting in Outlook that is 16 months from now, and send it to people in timezones that do and don't observe DST, and see if they all expect to show up at the same time (don't forget to include someone from Newfoundland who is in one of those fun :30 time zones). Even SQL Server added `DATETIMEOFFSET` but guess what? It isn't DST-aware.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the reply and suggestions. Fortunately all of my dates are from a single time zone, so for a one-off conversion I don't think I would have to consider all of the possibilities for all regions.  I updated my question with a quick function that I threw together.  Do you see any reason it wouldn't work?

Comment: I think that's an impossible to read and maintain function and since you only have one time zone to worry about that even begs more for a calendar table. In fact all you would need are two rows for each year (the day DST starts and the day it ends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

- You are basing which rule to use on the *current* date, rather than on the date provided in your input.  You should change that for sure.
- If I pass a value such as 2013-03-10 02:30, your function will assume that it was EDT, but in reality that time was invalid and should not exist in your data.  You should probably raise an error.
- If I pass a value such as 2013-11-03 01:30, your function will assume that it was EDT, but in reality it might have been in *either* EDT or EST.  You would need to have stored either an offset or a dst flag to disambiguate.  If it's not in the data, you have no choice but to assume one or the other.
- This function doesn't account for dates before 1987, which also had a DST rule change in the United States.  If you have data from before then, you should account for that as well.

Other than that, it looks fine.  Still, the points in the comments are correct.  This will only work for this one time zone, and you have no guarantees that the rules for this time zone won't change in the future.  I recommend you use convert your data to use UTC going forward.  You could use this function for the conversion if you like, or you could just as easily do it in application-level code.

Oh, and one other thing.  "Eastern Standard Time" or "EST" literally means UTC-5 without regard to daylight saving time at all.  Just like "Eastern Daylight Time" or "EDT" always means UTC-4.  I assume that you *meant* to say that your data is in "Eastern Time" in your question, which accommodates both.

If you *actually* meant EST, then your job is a lot simpler - just add 5 hours and call it done.  I bring this up because there are indeed scenarios where data is recorded without respect to daylight saving time.  (I believe there are some use cases in the financial sector that work like that.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt, I appreciate the feedback. Nice catch on the current date bug (I corrected this in my question). This function isn't going to be something that we use on a day to day basis. I'm just looking for a way to get my currently stored dates converted to UTC at the time we switch to Azure.  At the same time this is ran, permanent code will go into place to save all dates _initially_ in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I have just created own which takes a datetime variable in the future.  It follows the NIST rules stated below
However, my requirement was to return it as TEXT, and not a datetime, and I had to se MS SQL 2005.  Feel free to tweak.  :)

Rules based on [www.nist.gov](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/dst.cfm)

- Start    second sunday of March @ 02:00
- End      first sunday of november @ 02:00

My TimeZone : West Coast  (-8)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Local_Time]
(
    @dt     datetime    --  In UTC
)
RETURNS varchar(40)
AS
BEGIN

declare @local as datetime
declare @dw as int
declare @startDLS as datetime
declare @stopDLS as datetime
declare @tz as int
set @tz = -8        -- Time Zone - AKA sunny (and expensive) California

set @startDLS = 0  -- init
set @startDLS = cast (dateadd (yy, datepart(yy,@dt)-1900, @startDLS) as datetime)       --  Current Year
set @stopDLS = @startDLS                                                            --     Current Year
set @startDLS = cast (dateadd (mm, 2, @startDLS) as datetime)   -- Make date March 1st
set @stopDLS  = cast (dateadd (mm, 10, @stopDLS) as datetime)   -- Make date November 1st
set @dw = datepart(dw, @startDLS)

IF @dw = 1  
    BEGIN
        set @startDLS = cast (dateadd (dd, 7 , @startDLS) as datetime)
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        set @startDLS = cast (dateadd (dd, 15-@dw, @startDLS) as datetime)
    END
SET @startDLS = cast (dateadd (hh, 2, @startDLS) as datetime)

IF @dw = 1 
    BEGIN
        set @stopDLS = cast (dateadd (dd, 7 , @stopDLS) as datetime)
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        set @stopDLS = cast (dateadd (dd, 8-@dw, @stopDLS) as datetime)
    END
SET @stopDLS = cast (dateadd (hh, 2, @stopDLS) as datetime)

IF (@dt >= @startDLS ) and 
    (@dt < @stopDLS )
    BEGIN  --  @dt is within Daylight Savings Time Rules - Add an hour
        set @local = dateadd(hh, -7, @dt)
    END
ELSE    --  @dt is outside Daylight Savings Time Rules - No Adjustment
    BEGIN
        set @local = dateadd(hh, -8, @dt)
    END
return cast(@local as varchar(40) )

END
```