# Convert datetime of a timezone to GMT in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement of converting a record of time w.r.to timezone and compare it with current time.
For this, I want to convert datetime of a timezone to GMT timezone in SQL server.

i.e. (Jan 12 2015 11:30 A.M +5:30--->GMT standard time

Also is it possible to find out client's time zone from sql server?

Comment: You can find out the sql server's time zone from sql server, but if your client is a web client I have no idea how sql server would be able to know that.  You would want to get that information from your application and pass it through.

Comment: Ok. I understood. how can i convert a datetime with timezone to GMT time?

Comment: There are SO many articles on converting dates.  How many did you read?  I took your exact title and put it in google and came up with a [pretty nice article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491577/need-a-sql-server-function-to-convert-local-datetime-to-utc-that-supports-dst) that explains the nuance of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime is stored as a datetimeoffset (or convertible to it) you can simply convert to a datetime2 (assuming you want to keep the precision of the datetimeoffset):

```
declare @dt datetimeoffset

select @dt = 'Jan 12 2015 11:30 AM +05:30'

select convert(datetime2, @dt, 1)
```

Which returns the time in UTC:

```
2015-01-12 06:00:00.0000000
```

This has nothing to do with the users' timezone, as it is simply doing the timezone to UTC calculation based on your provided offset.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/43235/0)